# TypeError at /email/ getaddrinfo() argument 1 must be string or None

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-messages

i was trying to send message to candidate using Gmail as smtp, when i click send button im seeing the above error............................................................................................................................................................................................

views.py

```
    def email(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # save message to DB
        to_db = Email(
            status = request.POST.get('status'),
            name = request.POST.get('name'),
            email = request.POST.get('email'),
            message = request.POST.get('message'),
            subject = request.POST.get('subject'),
        )
        to_db.save()

        #Send email 
        form = EmailForm(request.POST)
        company = "TT Software Solutions"
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data["email"]
            subject = form.cleaned_data["subject"]
            message = form.cleaned_data["message"]

            mail = EmailMessage(subject, message, company, [email])
            mail.send()
            messages.success(request, 'Email sent successfully')
            return redirect('candidates')
    else:
        form = EmailForm()
        return render(request, {'form':form})
```

models.py

```
    class Email(models.Model):
    # Hidden
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    # Non Hidden
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    message = models.TextField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

template

```
    <form class="was-validated" action="{% url 'email' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="modal-body">
        <strong>To: <span class="text-primary">{{ candidate.first_name }} {{ candidate.last_name }}</span></strong>
        <hr>
        <!-- Hiden Inputs -->
        <input type="hidden" name="name" value="{{ candidate.first_name }} {{ candidate.last_name }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="email" value="{{ candidate.email }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="status" value="{{ candidate.Situation }}">
        <!-- Non Hiden Input -->
        <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Subject" required>
        <textarea name="message" class="form-control"  rows="8" placeholder="Message to candidate..." required></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-100">
            <i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp; Submit
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

forms.py

```
    
class EmailForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = forms.CharField(widget= forms.Textarea)
    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
```

settings.py

```
    # EMAILS (smtp server)
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'abiodunazeez230@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'app password here'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Answer (score 1):

You have set a bad host in your settings.py

```
# to remove !
EMAIL_HOST = 587
```

Comment: You have set twice the EMAIL_HOST line. Please read your code at this line. 587 is the PORT, not the HOST